# How to temporarily prevent mouse wheel double scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

When you have two scrollable panels, one (a kind of dialog) being over the other one, how do you make the front panel scrollable using the mouse wheel while fixing the one behind ?

To make my question clearer, I made a fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/kgdBQ/1/

When you wheel towards the top, the panel behind scrolls too, and I don't want that. I want the same lines being visible in the panel behind while the front panel is visible. What's the solution ?

HTML :

```
<div id=a>plenty of lines here</div>
<div id=b>here too</div>
```

CSS :

```
#b {
    position: fixed;
    top:20%; left:20%; right:20%; bottom:20%;
    overflow: auto;
    background: yellow;
}
```

JavaScript :

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#b').fadeIn() }, 1500);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a hack, but you could set the body to `overflow:hidden`, causing it not be able to scroll, then reset the overflow when foreground panel isnt showing :

```
document.body.style.overflow="hidden"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kgdBQ/3/

Comment: Your link isn't working for me. If it isn't evident, I don't want the scroll position of the panel behind to change at all (the same lines must keep being visible while the front panel is visible).

Comment: It works (I tested reverting the overflow works). I thought setting the overflow to hidden would reset the scroll, I was wrong... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,  http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/kgdBQ/4/

```
$('#a,#b').html(Array.apply(0,Array(500)).map(function(_,i){return i}).join('<br>'));
$(window).scrollTop(1000);
setTimeout(function(){ $('#b').fadeIn() }, 1500);
$('#b').hover(function() {
    $('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
}, function() {
    $('html, body').css('overflow', 'auto');
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see anything more compared to the other answer, apart the hover function that I don't want (*"I want the same lines being visible in the panel behind while the front panel is visible"*).

Comment: since you told temporarily prevent mouse wheel

Comment: Yes, it must be prevented for the panel behind while the front panel is visible. That's what Patrick achieved.

Comment: ok fine. I thought while you scroll the front panel you want the back panel to stop scrolling and vice versa. sorry